# How can I run BERT/ FinBert on my GPU instead of my CPU?

Tags: python, gpu, bert-language-model

I have trouble on running my code on my GPU instead of my CPU.

I am trying to run a FinBert code which classifies each sentence of a text as positive, negative or neutral. However, this code takes an eternity to run on my CPU. Because of that I am trying to run it on my GPU, but so far I was not able to figure out how to do it.

This is the code I want to execute on the GPU:

```
# first I am importing the necessary packages 
import pandas as pd
from transformers import BertTokenizer, BertForSequenceClassification
from transformers import pipeline 
import pandas as pd
import nltk

# then I load the pre-trained FinBert Model
finbert = BertForSequenceClassification.from_pretrained('yiyanghkust/finbert- 
tone',num_labels=3)
tokenizer = BertTokenizer.from_pretrained('yiyanghkust/finbert-tone')
# build model and pipeline
nlp = pipeline("sentiment-analysis", model=finbert, tokenizer=tokenizer)
```

Then I run the following for loop:

```
for i in range(0,len(data)):
print(i)
# access the text i from the data set
temp = data.iloc[i,1]
# tokenize the text to get the sentences of the text 
sentences = nltk.sent_tokenize(temp)
# apply FinBert-Model onto the sentences and save results in the variable "results"
results = nlp(sentences)
# get the filename of call i from clean_data 

# set j to 0 for the next for-loop
j = 0
# reset positive, neutral, and negative after each iteration over the second for-loop back to 0 to not inflate the count 
positive = 0
neutral = 0 
negative = 0 
# Create for loop to check for each sentence within the text whether FinBert classifies this sentence 
# as positive, neutral or negative 
for j in range (0,len(results)):
    label = results[j]["label"]
    if label == "Positive":
        positive = positive + 1
    elif label == "Neutral": 
        neutral = neutral + 1 
    else:
        negative = negative + 1  

# Calculate the sentiment scores
percentage_positive = positive / len(results)
percentage_negative = negative / len(results)
net_score = percentage_positive - percentage_negative 

# save the results in a DataFrame previously created 
results.iloc[i,1] = percentage_positive 
results.iloc[i,2] = percentage_negative 
results.iloc[i,3] = net_score
```

I have a NVIDIA GeForce MX130.

If I run the follwing code, it says that there is a GPU available:

```
import tensorflow as tf
print("Num GPUs Available: ", len(tf.config.list_physical_devices('GPU')))

output: Num GPUs Available:  1
```

And this code prints out:

```
tf.config.list_logical_devices('GPU')

output: [LogicalDevice(name='/device:GPU:0', device_type='GPU')]
```

I tried to run the code on the GPU on many ways including this one:

```
tf.debugging.set_log_device_placement(True)
# Place ops on the GPU
with tf.device('/GPU:0'):
   -> my code here
```

And running the following code also shows that my GPU is available:

```
import torch
use_cuda = torch.cuda.is_available()
print(use_cuda)

output: True


if use_cuda:
print('__CUDNN VERSION:', torch.backends.cudnn.version())
print('__Number CUDA Devices:', torch.cuda.device_count())
print('__CUDA Device Name:',torch.cuda.get_device_name(0))
print('__CUDA Device Total Memory 
[GB]:',torch.cuda.get_device_properties(0).total_memory/1e9)

output: 
[GB]:',torch.cuda.get_device_properties(0).total_memory/1e9)
__CUDNN VERSION: 8302
__Number CUDA Devices: 1
__CUDA Device Name: GeForce MX130
__CUDA Device Total Memory [GB]: 4.294967296
```

But still I am not able to run the code on the GPU.
What am I missing?

Best,
Kyle

Comment: is the model using pytorch? If so, you need to do `model.to("cuda")`

Comment: Yes it is using pytorch. But where do I need to add this in the code?

Comment: I now tried to add model.to("cuda") after this line: 
finbert = BertForSequenceClassification.from_pretrained('yiyanghkust/finbert- 
tone',num_labels=3)
finbert.to("cuda") 

But if I now execute the entire code it raises the following error: 

RuntimeError: Expected all tensors to be on the same device, but found at least two devices, cuda:0 and cpu! (when checking argument for argument index in method wrapper__index_select)

Answer (score 4):

In PyTorch, users have to manually move the model, data, and others to cuda themselves. Since your model is PyTorch, you need to move both the model and the data to `"cuda"`. Don't worry, you are going in the right direction:

```py
finbert = BertForSequenceClassification.from_pretrained('yiyanghkust/finbert- tone',num_labels=3) 
finbert.to("cuda")
...

nlp = pipeline("sentiment-analysis", model=finbert, tokenizer=tokenizer, device=0)
```

If it still raises the `RuntimeError` but with the same message, you can add that line with `to.("cuda")` as well.

Comment: sentences = nltk.sent_tokenize(temp).to("cuda")

Raises another error: 'list' object has no attribute 'to' 
sentences if a list of the different sentences of the text

Comment: Try `nlp = pipeline("sentiment-analysis", model=finbert, tokenizer=tokenizer, device=0)`

Comment: It is working now! There is no error but it is progressing quite slow and it issues the following warning: 
UserWarning: You seem to be using the pipelines sequentially on GPU. In order to maximize efficiency please use a dataset

Thank you very much!!!

Comment: BERT model is quite big, so it is understandable that it's slow. Btw, if it answers you question, consider accepting my answer :)

Comment: @Kyle_Stockton - Please mark helpful answers as accepted.   You have a lot of questions where you have not accepted an answer.